# Acessar uma hash/lista em uma class

Tags: ruby

Olá.

Eu sou um estudante intermediário em python, e recentemente eu comecei a estudar Ruby, porém, como toda nova linguagem, vem algumas pequenas dificuldades.

Minha dúvida é: Aonde está o erro nisso? Eu usei a função `has_key?()` fora da class, e funcionou perfeitamente, porém dentro da class, da o seguinte erro:

```
`FuncLogin': undefined method `has_key?' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Eu estou fazendo um programa simples de login e criação de conta, porém está dando esse erro. Segue o código completo:

```
class User
attr_accessor :login, :password

@contas = {"admin" => "pass"}

def initialize(login, password)
    @login    = login
    @password = password
end

def FuncLogin
    if @contas.has_key?(@login)
        if contas[@login] == @password
            return "Logado"
        else
            puts "Senha incorreta."
        end
    else
        return "Login inexistente."
    end
end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você atribui `@contas` dentro do escopo da classe. No Ruby, os escopos são muito importantes.

Veja o seguinte exemplo:

```
class Carro
  attr_accessor :modelo, :ano

  def andar
    puts 'Estou andando...'
  end
end
```

Esse `attr_accessor` é chamado do escopo de classe, pois não há instância definida. O `def andar`, é o mesmo caso. Você define um método na classe, para ser acessado por instâncias de objeto.

Para definir o valor de um campo `attr_accessor`, você deve fazer a nível de instância.

```
class Carro
  attr_accessor :modelo, :ano

  def initialize(modelo, ano)
    @modelo = modelo
    @ano = ano
  end

  def andar
    puts 'Estou andando...'
  end
end
```

O método construtor, `initialize` pode cuidar disso, já que é chamado à nível de instância.

```
tesla = Carro.new 'Tesla Model 3', 2018
tesla.andar
```

- [Ruby Instance Variables (Learn.co)](https://learn.co/lessons/ruby-instance-variables)
- [What is attr_accessor in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4371458/6241184)

Outro ponto: sempre siga as convenções. Para classes/módulos, utilize `PascalCase`. Já para variáveis e métodos, utilize `snake_case_minusculo`. Isso pode te gerar problemas mais tarde, já que no Ruby, todo objeto declarado com uma inicial maiúscula, isto é, `Abc` ou `ABC`, é uma constante.